# jQuery, Hiding elements on ready is always jumping on page load. how can this be avoided?

Tags: jquery, css, document-ready

This is the code.

I can't apply `display:none;`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#LeftNav li.navCatHead").not(":first").siblings("li").hide().end().end().first().addClass("open");
});
```

Comment: Using CSS would be my suggestion but you're saying you can't?

Comment: can you set ANY CSS on the #leftNav div, or just not display:none?

Answer (score 2):

why can't you  set "display:none"? Not sure about your scenario, but you probably can reverse the work flow a little bit

instead of show list initially, then hide certain ones based on some condition, try hide(display:none) lists initially, then show certain ones based on some condition.

This way you don't end up with some elements "show then disappear".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of applying `display:none`, (calling `$.hide()`), how about replacing the item you are trying to hide with an empty div that is set to the same size as whatever you are trying to hide?

Answer (score 1):

I often find that a nice alternative for `display:none;` is setting the opacity to 0 on load.

```
$("#LeftNav li.navCatHead").not(":first").siblings("li").css('opacity','0').end().end().first().addClass("open");
```

But rather than have such a long string to find the selector, I would just add a new class to each one and set that to `opacity: 0;` on page load as it will be much much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Don't wait for document ready. You can place your jQuery code at the bottom of the page before the closing body tag or alternatively, immediately after the elements in question.

```
            <!-- ...other code... -->
            <li>Sibling</li>
        </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // this should work...
            $("#LeftNav li.navCatHead").not(":first").siblings("li").hide().end().end().first().addClass("open");
        </script>
        <div class='content'>more stuff.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I used JQuery's `.hide()` function but because I placed the `<script>` at end of body the elements were visible for split second till the browser could reach the end of code and run the hiding function.

For the **solution** I increased the speed of `.hide()` function till it was so fast that the user can't see it.

It worked for me.

So now my function looks something like this.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#ids-or-classes").each(function(){ //.each is for multiple ids and classes 
        $(this).hide(0.00001); //lower the number faster the speed
        });
    });
```

Hope it helped, this was the first time I answered a question on our fav community. Cheers.